# How to load a css file depending on the current role

Tags: functions, user-roles, wp-enqueue-script

I have created a custom role (b2b) and I am trying to load a css file while the 'b2b' role is logged in or the administrator. I have tried the code below and I can't get it to work. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
function testCss() {

$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( $user->roles[0]=='administrator' || $user->roles[0]=='b2b' ) {


        // Add custom script.
        wp_enqueue_style(
            'jupiterx-child',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/b2bstyle.css'
        );


}

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','testCss', 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` check can result of a php notice because not logged in users have no roles and in that case `$user->roles[0]` will output `notice: array offest` (in short).

Aside from that, have you checked your console network to see if `/assets/css/b2bstyle.css` was loaded, even if you see status `404` you are in the right direction.

Your code seems to be correct, apart from the `if` check.

I would suggest doing something like this

```
function testCss () {
    // get user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // check if user has the following roles (administrator OR b2b)
    if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles) || in_array('b2b', $user->roles)) {
        wp_enqueue_style('jupiterx-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/b2bstyle.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testCss', 11);
```

If you check your console and go to network and see something like this

[image]

Click on it to reveal more information about the request, under Headers -> General, the very first line show you the request url, check to see that that is the correct one

[image]